# Interchanging a limit and an integral

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

**Prelude:** Suppose I have the following integral $$\int^1_0 dt \frac{t}{1-t}$$ which is divergent. I want to see how the divergence manifests. I can see two approaches

1. Rewrite the integral as $${\rm lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+}}\int^{1-p}_0 dt \frac{t}{1-t}$$ where $p>0$. I cannot see anything wrong with this approach.
2. Rewrite the integral as $$\int^1_0 dt {\rm lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+}}\frac{t}{1-t+pt}={\rm lim_{p\rightarrow 0^+}}\int^1_0 dt \frac{t}{1-t+pt}$$

**QUESTION:** Is the latter actually valid? In other words, do the operations of taking limits and integrating commute?

In both of these methods we obtain the same result.

Comment: In general limits and integrals do not commute. I really don't understand how to answer the question other that saying this. It's not like you can say that the divergence from the first integral equals the divergence from the second integral, unless you define what this means.

Comment: This is not valid in general. Another approach: you can subtract and add $1$ in the numerator, then do a change of variable to get a $p$-integral

Answer (score 1):

With the change of variable $t=(1-p)t'$ you get
$$
\int^{1-p}_0 \frac{t}{1-t}dt=(1-p)^2\int^{1}_0 \frac{t}{1-t+pt}dt.
$$
So your two integrals are not exactly the same, but their ratio tends to $1$ as $p\to0$.